# How to use push() with onDisconnect when user crashes

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Assume I have text messages stored in my database and are ordered by childByAutoId() using timestamps. Something like this:

```
-messages
    - dh28hd82jss
            ...
    - nds28h82h1a
            ...
    - di2jd92dhtd
            ...
```

What I am trying to do is push() a new message when user crashes.

This is how I typically use onDisconnect operations:

```
database.child("messages").onDisconnectUpdateChildValues( *update* ){ (error, ref) in
            if let error = error {
                print("\(error)")
            }
            completion(true)
        }
```

How can you use push() to append a new text message when a user crashes, using onDisconnect? (text message: "John Disconnected")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the exact value to write at the moment you call `onDisconnectUpdateChildValues`. So what you can do is determine a push key *now*, and then register to write that upon disconnect:

```
let key = database.childByAutoId().key
database.child("messages").child(key).onDisconnectUpdateChildValues([
  "text": "Hello world"
])
```

Comment: Any idea why data "Database.database().reference().push()" doesn't exit? I think swift doesn't have push() and I must use childByAutoId() directly?

Thank you Puf

Comment: Oops, good point. On iOS it's indeed `childByAutoId`. I updated my answer.